# Is there any way to rewrite an url converting the content between parenthses in querystring?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm looking for a .htaccess code that is able to transform an url like this

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/apis/endpoints/myfunction(1234,ABCDEFG,...,4344)
```

into

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/apis/endpoints/index.php?f=myfunction&a1=1234&a2=ABCDEFG&...aN=4344
```

I've tried using:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?index.php=$1&argument=$2 [L,QSA]
```

But I don't know how to do it for a flexible number of arguments. It looks like I'm forced to do it with a given number of arguments.
For information: the need comes for make more easy to use some functions (API) for my website users.
Any clue?

P.S. as arkascha pointed out, this is not a standard REST API, I was worried to bore you with my stuff, but if you asked me let me explain. If fact it is not a REST API. Not all the API has to be RESTful. As you know everyone has the possibility to develop his own scheme. The notation f(x,y,z) is very familiar to everyone works in math and for them it's by far easier to understand rather then /f/x/y/z. My users are mathematical users and the API I wrote were designed to provide very specific and complicated stuff adopting the same facilities in use for informatic APIs but in this case I just wanted to have something that was more familiar and easy to understand for them. An example:
Everyone understand if i ask what will happen if I call the following URI ?:

https://www.example.com/api/pythagoras(3,4) , you'll not be surprised that the result will be 5 ;-) 
but if I write:
https://www.example.com/api/pythegoras/3/4 the result might not be so obvious to people who ignore what is a REST API :-O.
This was the only aim of this question. Thanks for giving me the chance to explain.

Comment: I would just rewrite it to this `?f=myfunction&a=1234,ABCDEFG,4344` and then `explode(',', $_GET['a'])` in PHP.  Simpler.

Comment: Something similar to `^([^(]+)\(([^)]+)$ index.php?f=$1&a=$2`

Comment: myfunction is just a text holder coul be anything, I cannot write all the functions that it's possible to call inside a huge .htaccess file, that's why I need to do it dinamically. 
In other words:
http://www.mywebsite.com/apis/endpoints/pitagora(1234,4344)
must be remapped to 
http://www.mywebsite.com/apis/endpoints/index.php?f=pitagora&a1=1234&a2=4344

but also
http://www.mywebsite.com/apis/endpoints/euler(1234,4344,345)
must be remapped to 
http://www.mywebsite.com/apis/endpoints/index.php?f=euler&a1=1234&a2=4344&a3=345

with the same .htaccess

Comment: Do you see `myfunction` anywhere in the regex?  The first comment was an example showing the format and how to explode it in PHP.

Comment: What kind of API uses such a strange URL scheme? Strictly speaking that is not invalid, but it is obvious that this will cause issues. Usually REST APIs use a scheme like `/apis/endpoints/myfunction/1234/ABCDEFG/.../4344` ...

Comment: @arkascha, than you for your question, I wrote the answer in P.S. in my description.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, your suggestion was helpful for me to find a working solution ;-) 
See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to the stuff (working on AbraCadaver suggestion) by adding the following to my .htaccess in the folder containing my index.php script:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?&f=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then I wrote the code in PHP into index.php to obtain the behavior I was looking for.
In the PHP file I parsed the string 'myfunction(1234,ABCDEFG,...,4344)' retrieved from superglobal $_GET. I removed the 'f' element from the $_GET and populated it with the function argument 1234,ABCDEFG,...,4344 as they were sent by a query-string. Doing that I can invoke the script myfunction as it was called in the canonical GET with parameters.